# Hiding web pages extensions

Tags: web-applications

Just outta curiosity, how do people hide their webpage extension? Or better yet hide the name of the page itself.

For example here, at the asking question form, I can only see `stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` , not any aspx files thought from what I knew, stackexchange is developed on .NET technologies.

Is there any benefits of doing so? and how?

Comment: Surely asp.net doesn't actually *require* .aspx in the URL?

Comment: how to do so? Most of the webapp that I developed end up with aspx at the end of the web pages. Is there any setting?

Answer (score 0):

For Example 
Apache `ModRewrite`

Besides, you should understand that `URI`!=`filename`